# Rock Band 3 and Ion Drum Rocker cymbals

Tags: rock-band-3

in Rock Band 3, when using the Ion Drum Rocker do the cymbals register as separate hits?  I heard in pro mode Rock Band 3 can do this.  But is the Ion Drum Rocker compatible?  Also is pro mode insanely difficult, or can you tame it down a bit for the more novice drummer?  :)

Answer (score 4):

In Rock Band 3 Pro Drum mode, the cymbals show up differently on the tracks. They will show as circles instead of rectangles on the yellow, blue and green tracks. You must not only hit the correct color, but hit the drum or the cymbal as shown. Hitting the yellow drum pad when the yellow cymbal is shown counts as a miss.

You can adjust the difficulty just like in regular drums. There are Easy, Medium, Hard, and Expert versions of each song, as in regular drums.

The ION Drum rocker is compatible, but only comes with two cymbals. There can be a total of three used in the tracks (for yellow, blue and green). If you do not have all three cymbals, there is a setting in the game that allows you to enable only the cymbals you have. For example, if you have only two, you can set it to where only the yellow and green cymbals symbols will appear. The blue pad will then always show as a drum.

Comment: damn, beat me to it.   I have a Ion Drumset and love it.  The only thing I recommend is getting an Anti-stactic pad to put your drumset on.  I was having a lot of static discharge with my set (as I play on the carpet and the set is full metal).  The discharge would cause random hits mid song.

Comment: You can though buy the cymbal expansion pack, for the third cymbal, right?

Comment: As long as it is Ion Compatible, i dont see why not.

Comment: The cymbal expansions for the ION seem to be hard to find on Amazon. I don't know how rare they are now. It looks like the controller comes with one cymbal, not two like I thought.

Comment: Another alternative is to get an electronic drum kit and MIDI converter. I purchased a Yamaha DTX explorer kit, which comes with three cymbals. It's more money than the ION, but can be used as a drum set outside the game.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it comes with two.

Comment: Mine came with two cymbals